# Dividing a list by another with some "0"s in the denominator list

Tags: python, operator-keyword

I have the following to divide one list by another (they are vectors):

```
from operator import truediv
x = [1,0,0,7]
y = [2,3,0,5]
z = map(truediv,x,y)
```

Is there a way to skip the 0's in the y vector? Hopefully not adding too much iteration. My actual lists are obviously much longer (about 1200 elements each) than this and there's lots of them.

Comment: What must happen in `z` when the number in `y` is 0? Does the item have to be ignored or do you want to have the value of `x` for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
from __future__ import division
z = [xx / yy for xx, yy in zip(x, y) if yy]
# or
default = 0  # just a guess...
z = [xx / yy if yy else default for xx, yy in zip(x, y)]
```

filtering while iterating is one of the things that list-comprehensions do much more expressively than you can get in a more functional style of programming (e.g. using `map`).  There *are* times when `map` is more convenient (e.g. when the function being applied is more complex), but for this simple case I'd go with the list-comprehension (or generator expression).

Comment: Yes! The second option only though! I don't wan't to remove any elements, even if the denominator is 0

Comment: @Ecanales -- Yeah, you didn't really specify what you want to happen for that case so I tried to answer with a couple options that seemed like they might be reasonable.